# Tomcat 5.5: The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat5.5

I'm having some trouble getting my web app to launch on my server. The URL is:
http://www.apollowebworks.com/kmsales/ItemSearch.do

It used to work fine, and still runs on my local build using Eclipse. I noticed it wasn't working anymore sometime after my hosting provider informed me that they were migrating to a new server.

This is the error I'm getting:

> HTTP Status 404 - /kmsales/ItemSearch.do
>
> type Status report
>
> message /kmsales/ItemSearch.do
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.42

I find it suspicious that it's posting "Apache Tomcat/7.0.42". My host has Tomcat 5.5. I am running it on a 5.5 build locally. I was initially running it on a higher build, and I'm thinking maybe some of my xml files or jars might still reference the wrong Tomcat somehow. I can't find that anywhere though. Any idea where else to look?

The libraries I'm using are:

- javacsv.jar
- jstl.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar
- standard.jar

Comment: use your local tomcat 7, try to run it and then show the logs in error

Answer (score 0):

You said "migrating to a new server". This is most likely why you see there Tomcat 7. I think you need to check with your provider to see what exactly they migrated. Maybe your app wasn't copied to the new Tomcat. In any case you really need to see if your app is there where it should be and, if it is, check the log files.

Comment: By "new server" I meant "different physical hardware location." The RELEASE-NOTES file in my Tomcat directory still says "Apache Tomcat Version 5.5.36".

Comment: Maybe that's not the Tomcat that's actually running your app...